# Commenting out an element of a multiline list

Tags: comments

Is it possible to comment out one element of a multiline list? Or, in general, can you combine line continuations with comments?

(Lightly modified from my vimrc)

```
[
    \'eslint',
    \'tsserver',
    \'xo'
\]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or, in general, can you combine line continuations with comments?

Yes, but it must consist of three symbols (see `:h line-continuation-comment`): quote, backslash and **space**.

As it stands in your example code right now, it won't work.

The following will work:

```
[
    "\ 'eslint',
    \'tsserver',
    \'xo'
\]
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why I didn't notice that while scrolling down. Thanks. At the very least, this should be easily searchable now.